Low initial validation loss from the first epoch?
The initial validation loss is low from the first epoch and then decreases slightly. What does this actually mean? Does it indicate that the model can effectively and quickly identify patterns for this task?
I can see that the model works in practice, but the results (some image restoration) aren’t ideal yet, so I want to improve its performance even further.

Given this low loss from the first epoch, should I focus on training with more data or on adjusting the architecture and layers to be even more complex, etc.?

Given the small differences between the first epoch and the last, is it more likely that the model was barely able to improve performance during these epochs, or could the difference in loss still be meaningful?


The dataset count was of 10,000 images - 0.9 for training, 0.1 for validation.
First epoch loss:
Epoch [1/50], Training Loss: 0.026428, Validation Loss: 0.023727
Last epoch and plateau:
Epoch [34/50], Training Loss: 0.020682, Validation Loss: 0.020651
